# Telerik Reporting over SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, telerik, telerik-reporting

Broad question is: Is there anything Telerik Reporting can do that SSRS (2005) cannot?

Specifics: We're looking to migrate our current Reporting infrastructure from in-house ASP.NET + Crystal (VS Edition) to something else.

Ignoring the cost factor (we have a Telerik license), is there any pros or cons to going with Telerik over SSRS?

Key elements we need are:

- generate reports from a custom ASP.NET application
- schedule reports
- email reports on demand or on a schedule
- pdf output, drilldown html
- massage the dataset in `C#` before passing it to the rendering engine

Any experiences or sites that point out advantages or limitations (with either engine) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

SSRS is a **server-based** reporting system whereas Telerik Reporting is purely an **embedded** reporting tool. You should compare Telerik Reporting to SSRS ReportViewer control in **[local processing mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251704.aspx)**, not the whole SSRS system, unless you intend to use the SSRS server too. I think this is the first question to answer: you should evaluate the pros and cons of using a report server.

The usual reason of choosing embedded reporting is to **avoid a server dependency**. If you are an application developer and deploy your application to multiple sites, you would have to support multiple SSRS installation in addition to your application. Telerik reports compile to a dll that you can deploy with your application easily.

Generally, server-based SSRS is more feature-rich than Telerik reporting, especially the SSRS 2008 [tablix](http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2007/08/12/tablix-the-crown-jewel.aspx) is handy. I think that Telerik Reporting has supported crosstabs only from Q1 2009. It does not support interactive features like drilldown. You should see the [known limitations](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/known-limitations-of-telerik-reporting.aspx) of Telerik reporting and also the [substantial improvements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630399.aspx) in SSRS 2008 compared to SSRS 2005. On the other hand, ReportViewer in local mode understands RDL 2005 only, so you are limited to SSRS 2005 features.

Now, it is easier to look at your requirements.

**Generating reports from a custom ASP.NET application**

- SSRS Server: Microsoft ReportViewer web control configured for [remote processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075.aspx) views the reports processed and rendered by an SSRS server
- SSRS local mode: Microsoft  ReportViewer processes and renders the local RDL 2005 report definitions
- Telerik: Telerik ReportViewer processes and renders reports. Reports can be deployed as a single dll with all the resources (images etc.) embedded. This is the strong point of Telerik reporting.

**Scheduling reports**

- SSRS: Server-side feature, not supported in local mode
- Telerik : Not supported

**Email reports on demand or on a schedule**

- SSRS : Server-side feature, not supported in local mode
- Telerik: Not supported

**Pdf output**

- SSRS: Various output formats in server mode. In local mode, ReportViewer supports only Excel and PDF
- Telerik: Various output formats, including pdf

**Drilldown html**

- SSRS Server: Drilldown to a subreport (another RDL report definition) with parameter passing, static urls in report elements
- SSRS local mode: Static urls but no interactive features
- Telerik: Static urls but no interactive features

**Massage the dataset in C# before passing it to the rendering engine**

- SSRS Server: Supports report datasets defined in RDL, OLEDB compatible
  data sources, XML data, Integration Services packages and standard .NET providers
- SSRS local mode: This quote is directly from Lachev's book (p.525):

> ReportViewer supports two types of
>   data sources in local processing mode:
>   a dataset that contains an ADO.NET
>   DataTable object or an enumerable
>   collection of business objects.
>   ReportViewer Windows Forms also
>   supports binding to instances of
>   System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource and
>   to System.Type. Report Viewer Web
>   server supports binding to an instance
>   of System.Web.UI.IDataSource.

- Telerik: any DataSet or DataView can be set as a datasource at runtime

Given your key elements, and assuming that you are doing internal reporting inside a corporate firewall, I'd definitely recommend using an SSRS server. Try to get one SQL Server 2008 licence or use SQL 2008 Express as a reporting server. But if you absolutely have to use embedded reporting, Telerik is probably a better choice, at least until Microsoft ReportViewer supports RDL 2008 in local mode. This new ReportViewer should be shipped with Visual Studio 2010.

For SSRS, I recommend reading Teo Lachev's [Applied Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.prologika.com/Books/0976635313/Book.aspx). Sample chapters are available at the [book's site](http://www.prologika.com/Books/0976635313/Resources/sample_chapters.pdf) the and in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=2utfzCzsa48C&printsec=frontcover&dq=teo+lachev&ei=IDO2SpnvDo6CyQTTu9SCDw&hl=fi#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

Telerik Reporting has excellent support too. Developing Telerik reports relies heavily on [samples](http://demos.telerik.com/reporting/) and [support forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting.aspx).

I have also written blog posts on [embedded reporting](http://www.flowmarks.com/2009/03/on-embedded-reporting-mindset-few-tips.html) and [Telerik Reporting](http://www.flowmarks.com/2009/09/experiences-with-telerik-reporting.html) in particular.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I've yet to dig into all the links you provided, but the first 5 alone help so much. Thank you.

Comment: The latest version of the Telerik reporting does support custom business collections too, FYI.

Comment: There are a few important things to add here... SSRS (server-side) is an extremely heavyweight solution intended for creating internal reports. In the enterprise it might make sense, but we used it in a small shop and it was a full-on nightmare. We had a multi-tenant situation and it just isn't meant to provide secure customer-facing reports. We later used it client-side only with better results, but the report builder remains primitive even compared to what Access had years ago, tasks that should be easy are arcane and inscrutable, and it only renders correctly in IE. Small teams beware.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to [mika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460/mika)'s reply regarding Telerik interactivity:

Their [reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) now offers a few interactivity features, namely navigating to a subreport (drill-through), navigate to a bookmark, and navigate to URL. Their current roadmap mentions that they will add interactive sorting and drill-down by the end of 2011. These should bring their reporting product much closer to SSRS in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add some new information about Telerik's solution.

Some of the things that were previously not supported, such as **Scheduling reports** and **Email reports on demand or on a schedule** are now available as part of the Telerik Report Server product. The Report Server comes with the Report Designer mentioned above. More information about if is available [here](http://www.telerik.com/report-server).

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons we stopped using SSRS and went with Telerik is because Telerik has much better support across browsers. Naturally, one would not expect MS to provide equal support for a rival product when it comes to browser compatibility.
Since you are planning one doing a web based application this may be a factor.

I first started using Telerik reporting version 2010 Q2 and never had an issue linking reports over a web app to provide drill-down or linking functionality. It was quite simple and intuitive.

Another thing to think about is that SSRS report files which are RDL files, whereas a Telerik report is compiled into your app. If you need to change your report you'll need to recompile and redeploy your app. For RDL files, you simply upload them to the SSRS server. I still prefer Telerik though, even though it means a slightly longer SDLC for a change request.

Another thing that grinds my noodle is that as long as we used SSRS we had to have both VS 2008 and 2010 installed, because VS 2010 does not have support for designing RDL reports like 2008 has (BIDS is basically a scaled down version of VS 2008: [Visual Studio 2010 Reporting Services Projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732983/visual-studio-2010-reporting-services-projects) )

With Telerik we can stick to using VS 2010.

Comment on "Telerik Reporting has excellent support too. Developing Telerik reports relies heavily on samples and support forums.":
No. You're making an assumption. I have created many complex reports without needing *any* direction from forums/sample/etc - its a very intuitive tool. I am sure there are many developers out there who have been able to do just fine without "heavy" reliance on the forums/samples - its not rocket science, it's cake.

Comment: syncfusion has an ssrs viewer that is quite cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

SSRS Local mode is not supported in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions Telerik Reporting have Report Designer that is tool like Report Builder and the report viewer support XML report definitions (trdx). So no compiling is required if you change the reports.