# Visual Studio 2010 Reporting Services Projects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

So, it seems that Visual Studio 2010 does not support SSRS projects. At least not old ones.. Does anyone know what the status on this situation is and whether one can author new SSRS reports using VS2010 or if one should just use VS2008 BIDS?

Comment: it never did. You need to go thru Business Intelligence Studio which is part of SQL server client tools

Comment: I find that very hard to believe that VS2010 would jettison SSRS development.  If so, that does not bode well for the future.

Comment: I don't think they are jettisoning - they just lag behind in developing BIDS compared to the RTM of VS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 R2 = SQL Server 2010 (ish)

"R2 doesn't integrate with Visual Studio 2010 as it targets VS 2008 only" read more here:

http://prologika.com/CS/blogs/blog/archive/2010/03/16/bids-integration-story-in-r2-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You need the BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) installedm, which is part of SQL tools.

However, [as usual for VS/SSRS](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/01/SSRS-Incompatible) it max be an implicit upgrade of your reports

And some stuff on the [VS team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/robertbruckner/archive/2009/01/19/better-report-viewing-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server Business Development uses the Visual Studio shell.  Because SQL 2008 and VS2010 were under development at the same time, they had to use the VS2008 shell.

Microsoft has released the shell as a component that anyone can use and redistribute.

Answer (score 4):

According to the release notes of the upcoming release of SQL Server 2012,

> In SQL Server 2012, SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is an add-in to
>   Visual Studio 2010. Report server projects created in SQL Server 2008
>   R2 can be opened directly into SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). Projects
>   created in SQL Server 2008 are automatically upgraded when opened in
>   SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). For ease of managing your existing and
>   new report server projects, you can continue to add projects created
>   in SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 to a SQL Server 2012
>   business intelligence solution.
>
> You can also continue to open and edit reports that use the 2005 and
>   2008 RDL schemas in SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). However, if you add
>   a report item that is not compatible with the schema used by a report,
>   the report will be automatically upgraded to the 2010 RDL schema.

[What's New (Reporting Services)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170438.aspx#SSDT10)

Answer (score 1):

With Service Pack 1 and SQL 2012 SSDT Shared Components you can now work on SSRS reports in VS2010 and still deploy them to 2008 and 2008 R2 SQL Servers.

SP1: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691